# Error parsing xml using ansible lxml module

Tags: python-3.x, xml, pip, ansible, lxml

Below is my Ansible playbook to print `<driver_name>` from XML using Ansible `lxml` Python plugin.

```yaml
---
- name: ReadJsonfile
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Print drivers
      community.general.xml:
        path: jdbc.xml.bkp
        xpath: /jdbc_data_source/jdbc_driver_params/driver_name
      register: hits

    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: hits
```

I got the below error running the playbook:

> Error while parsing document: jdbc.xml.bkp (Unsupported encoding UTF_8

One of the solutions proposed was to delete the below first line from the xml

Below is the first line that I removed from the XML

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF_8'?>
```

Below is my current XML file:

```xml
<jdbc_data_source xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema_instance" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source/1.0/jdbc_data_source.xsd">
  <jdbc_driver_params>
    <driver_name>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver_name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <driver_name>tomcat.jdbc.TomcatDriver</driver_name>
  </jdbc_driver_params>
</jdbc_data_source>
```

Unfortunately, I now get the below error:

```
TASK [Print drivers] *****************************************************************************
Tuesday 29 March 2022  05:04:49 -0500 (0:00:01.427)       0:00:01.443 *********
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/wladmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1648548289.1452537-29064-207706807914112/AnsiballZ_xml.py\", line 107, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/wladmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1648548289.1452537-29064-207706807914112/AnsiballZ_xml.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/wladmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1648548289.1452537-29064-207706807914112/AnsiballZ_xml.py\", line 47, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.modules.xml', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.modules.xml', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 207, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 97, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 87, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.xml_payload_yt4drx6g/ansible_community.general.xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py\", line 987, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.xml_payload_yt4drx6g/ansible_community.general.xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py\", line 977, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.xml_payload_yt4drx6g/ansible_community.general.xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py\", line 656, in ensure_xpath_exists\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.xml_payload_yt4drx6g/ansible_community.general.xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py\", line 594, in check_or_make_target\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.xml_payload_yt4drx6g/ansible_community.general.xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py\", line 593, in check_or_make_target\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.xml_payload_yt4drx6g/ansible_community.general.xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py\", line 417, in is_node\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.xml_payload_yt4drx6g/ansible_community.general.xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py\", line 441, in xpath_matches\n  File \"src/lxml/etree.pyx\", line 2311, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath\n  File \"src/lxml/xpath.pxi\", line 357, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__\n  File \"src/lxml/xpath.pxi\", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result\nlxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP *************
```

I'm on Ansible core version

```
ansible [core 2.12.3]
python version = 3.8.12 (default, Mar 29 2022, 01:40:53) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
```

```
Name: lxml
Version: 4.8.0
```

Can you please suggest what is the issue and how to overcome it?

Comment: `"UTF_8"` is not a valid XML encoding. You meant `"UTF-8"`. Since you've edited the file manually in a text editor, and the encoding declaration was probably invalid all-along, double-check that the file *really* is saved in the UTF-8 encoding when you correct it.

Comment: *"One of the solutions proposed was to delete the below first line from the xml"* - ...the better option is to make sure that no garbage is written in that line. ;)

Comment: Well, @Tomalak, I was the one proposing to actually **fix** it in a local copy and not remove it, but that is because the OP said the file was a third party vendor XML.

Comment: Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71650245/2123530

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε It would still be best to go and the tell vendor to fix their garbage XML, that's an embarrassing output to produce, because it means they are piecing together their XML from strings instead of using an XML API, and they are letting someone do it who has no idea of XML, and they are not testing the things they generate.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you do have an namespace defined in your XML:

```xml
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source"
```

And you need to take that into consideration and map it, with the [`namespaces`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html#parameter-namespaces) parameter.

So, here should be your task:

```yaml
- community.general.xml:
  path: jdbc.xml.bkp
    xpath: /x:jdbc_data_source/x:jdbc_driver_params/x:driver_name
    namespaces:
      x: http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source
    content: text
  register: hits
```

If you need a simple list of those values:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: hits.matches | map('dict2items') | flatten | map(attribute="value")
```

---

Given the three tasks:

```yaml
- community.general.xml:
    path: jdbc.xml.bkp
    xpath: /x:jdbc_data_source/x:jdbc_driver_params/x:driver_name
    namespaces:
      x: http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source
    content: text
  register: hits

- debug:
    var: hits.matches

- debug:
    var: hits.matches | map('dict2items') | flatten | map(attribute="value")
```

This yields:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  hits.matches:
  - '{http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source}driver_name': oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  - '{http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc_data_source}driver_name': tomcat.jdbc.TomcatDriver

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  hits.matches | map('dict2items') | flatten | map(attribute="value"):
  - oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  - tomcat.jdbc.TomcatDriver
```

Comment: how to i print an list like this -> `['oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver','tomcat.jdbc.TomcatDriver']` ?

Comment: `hits.matches | map('dict2items') | flatten | map(attribute="value")`